# Javascript array to int

Tags: javascript

I've problem to read array.

i have demo array like this only numbers

var test = [0.00000001 ,-0.0000002 ,-0.0000002 ,0.0000002 ,0.0000002 ,];

and another array that i created like this:

```
var buffer = [];

$.get("../../test/pop/test.txt", 
    function(txt, status, jqXHR ) {
        var lines = txt.split("\n");
        for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i++) {
            buffer.push((lines[+i]));  

        }

    }, 
    "text"  
 );
```

when i alert(buffer); and alert(test);

i have same result but when i use buffer array as data it can't show someting, it looks like string or something i dont know. Who can help me?

Comment: how is your test.txt looks like?

Comment: like this https://ibb.co/joG7Ev

Comment: alert() is always shows data as string. what output do you have on console.log (buffer)  ?

Comment: yes is see, ["0.0000005 ", "-0.0000002 ", "0.00000001 ", "-0.0000002 ", "-0.0000002 ", ""]

how can i recover to [0.0000005 , -0.0000002 , 0.00000001 , -0.0000002 , -0.0000002 , ]

Answer (score 0):

You need simply convert string with to number. your `+` is on incorrect place. Try this:

```
var buffer = [];

$.get("../../test/pop/test.txt", 
    function(txt, status, jqXHR ) {
        var lines = txt.split("\n");
        for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (lines[i]) {
              buffer.push(+lines[i]);  
            }
        }

    }, 
    "text"  
 );
```